# Android openGL oddity, resetting variables

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm building an Android app with a simple 3D engine. It was working earlier, but was incredibly messy. I've refactored the heck out of it, but I did little to the 3D engine. Now I'm running into a very strange problem where calling translatef within the draw() method (which itself is called from within onDrawFrame within the class that implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer) does not use the current value of the x/z float variables, which are scoped to the class. I cannot explain it. There is zero code that would reset them to their initial values, but that's what is happening. The only time these variables are touched are when the class is instantiated (done once, never touched again), when they change due to user input (verified as accurate with the debugger at every point possible), and when translatef is called, at which point they are only read.

The thing is, they are always the initial value that was passed to the constructor when read by the translatef method, but are accurate otherwise at any other point in the class when they are used or altered. If, say, we set z to z + 1, it remains at that value regardless of the value read by translatef. What gives? I'm at a loss as to why the draw() and/or translatef() methods are somehow sticking to the original values and not reading the modified values. I'm utilizing GL ES 1.0 and Android 2.2 as my testing platform.

There's too much to just dump it all here, but this should be sufficient to get the problem across:

```
private float movex, movez;

public GLEngine(){
    //The values are set in the constructor and are accurate at this point.
    movex = Controller.getX();
    movey = Controller.getZ();
}

public void move(float x, float z){
    //Again, debugging in here shows that the values are being set properly.
    movex = x;
    movez = z;
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){
    //Debugging anywhere within this method shows only the values for movex and
    //movez that were set in the constructor.
    ...
    gl.translatef(movex, .5f, movez);
    ...
```

I got a tip to make movex and movez volatile as this was likely related to threading issues (although I have not explicitly declared any threads here), but that didn't help.

As both values are held outside the class, I was able to make this work by pulling them from the controller in the onDrawFrame method, but this requires the variables to be pulled and additional operations to be performed on them on every draw, which is costly. There has to be a better way...

Comment: Please show your actual code, don't try to describe it (it's too ambiguous).

Answer (score 0):

Since `x` and `z` are `private` variables, it should be easy to track down.

You are only ever setting them via your `move` method. To find this out, delete or comment out your `move` method (temporarily) and do a save. Eclipse will highlight any code that is now broken as a result.

Once you are sure that all changes for `x` and `z` are going through the `move` method, set a breakpoint there. (You can set conditional breakpoints as well).

If you stop at a breakpoint, you can can see which method called move.

This should let you track the problem down.